# How can I start grub using grub on my new installation

Tags: linux, grub

I have installed a Scientific Linux 6 (like Centos 6) on my first drive sda and use it as my working linux, in order to continue to user my working ditribution I have Installed a Scientific Linux 7 on sdb.

Using boot priority on bios setup I am able to start SL 6 on sda or SL7 on sdb

Is it possible to configure grub on sda in so that at startup it will also run the grub boot loader on sdb, so choose which distribution start ? 
My intention is to let installed grub on sdb in order to have ready the new SL7 installation as soon as I finish configure it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this simply by updating your GRUB menu with both disks present (preferably on the CentOS 7 host).

The command `grub-mkconfig` will output a new grub configuration file, produced by running through a series of scripts for automatically detecting operating systems. It will detect Cent6 and a bootloader on that other drive, and create an appropriate menu entry for it. This will typically be a chainloader entry, which depends on the bootloader still being intact on the Cent 6 installation, so don't wipe that out.

You can run the following command on the CentOS 7 host to get this result (replacing the output GRUB configuration file with a valid path, in case yours differs):

`# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`